# How to create facebook application via Facebook Developer Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, canvas, facebook

I'm trying to create a basic application, i created facebook application before but everything has been changed :(

I looked every where to create a basic application, but now i'm getting mad because there isn't any working sample. Because of the changed links, facebook api changes, facebook wiki changes i couldn't find a working copy.

I wonder if anyone can help me to write a basic app that gets permission to write user name to screen in facebook developer toolkit asp.net. I looked computerbeacon.net, codeplex, and some other pages but i couldn't succeed, so please don't give me the links :)

Edit: I' m adding some screenshots and some codes, it will may be help you to find my problem.

Here some screenshots from fb;

This is the core settings,
[image]

This is the Facebook integration settings,
[image]

Web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="FaceBookAPIKey" value="MyapiKey"/>
    <add key="FaceBookSecretKey" value="MyapiSecret"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

My Default.aspx file;

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Facebook.Web" Namespace="Facebook.Web" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:CanvasFBMLLoginControl ID="CanvasFBMLLoginControl1" runat="server" RequireLogin="true" />
```

Result;

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problems.

please make sure that

please fill canvas url with your webapp correct URL when you create facebook application

I paste here the following running example that update my status in facebook profile

the following  code in markeup

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
        <%--<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>  
        <fb:prompt-permission perms="status_update"> Grant permission for status updates </fb:prompt-permission>
    </form>
```

and the following in form page  to send status

```
/// <summary>
        /// To send status to your facebook account
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="statusMessage">status message</param>
        public bool publishToFaceBook(string statusMessage)
        {
            //please Change call back url in FB app accoroding to your web site application
             Facebook.Rest.Api Api;
             Facebook.Session.ConnectSession _connectSession;
             _connectSession = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FaceBookAPIKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FaceBookSecretKey"]);

            bool sucess=false;
            if (_connectSession.IsConnected())
            {
                try
                {
                    Api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(_connectSession);
                    Facebook.Schema.user u = Api.Users.GetInfo();
                    Facebook.Schema.user_status _status = new Facebook.Schema.user_status();

                    Api.Users.SetStatus(statusMessage);

                    sucess = true;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sucess = false;
                }

            }
            return sucess;
        }
```

I hope that help you

Best Regards,

Mohammed Thabet Zaky

Comment: thanks for your help but it didn't work again. I will edit my question for details may be after that you can help me.

Comment: Xenon,you should fill canvas url with the correct url of your web application page that interact with facebook application for example you shoulf fill in Canvas url     http ://localhost:58257/    if your web page    http ://localhost:58257/frmSocial.aspx      and canvas type is IFrame